# r- The confuse details of findCorrelation() (caret package) when setting exact=True

Tags: r, r-caret

According to the [findCorrelation() document](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-77/topics/findCorrelation) I run the official example as shown below:

Code:

```
library(caret)

R1 <- structure(c(1, 0.86, 0.56, 0.32, 0.85, 0.86, 1, 0.01, 0.74, 0.32, 
                  0.56, 0.01, 1, 0.65, 0.91, 0.32, 0.74, 0.65, 1, 0.36,
                  0.85, 0.32, 0.91, 0.36, 1), 
                .Dim = c(5L, 5L))


colnames(R1) <- rownames(R1) <- paste0("x", 1:ncol(R1))

findCorrelation(R1, cutoff = .6, exact = TRUE, names = TRUE
                ,verbose = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
> findCorrelation(R1, cutoff = .6, exact = TRUE, names = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
## Compare row 1  and column  5 with corr  0.85 
##   Means:  0.648 vs 0.545 so flagging column 1 
## Compare row 5  and column  3 with corr  0.91 
##   Means:  0.53 vs 0.49 so flagging column 5 
## Compare row 3  and column  4 with corr  0.65 
##   Means:  0.33 vs 0.352 so flagging column 4 
## All correlations <= 0.6 
## [1] "x1" "x5" "x4"
```

I have no idea how the computation process works, i. e. why there are first compared `row 1` and `column 5`, and how the mean is calculated, even after I have read [the source file](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/findCorrelation.R).

I hope that someone could explain the algorithm with the help of my example.

Answer (score 0):

First, it determines the average absolute correlation for each variable. Columns `x1` and `x5` have the highest average (`mean(c(0.85, 0.56, 0.32, 0.86))` and `mean(c(0.85, 0.9, 0.36, 0.32))` respectively), so it looks to remove one of these on the first step. It finds `x1` to be the most globally offensive, so it removes it.

After that, it recomputes and compares `x5` and `x3` using the same process.

It stops after removing three columns since all pairwise correlations are below your threshold.

Comment: Hi Max, I think the confusion is that the output shows the first comparison of 0.648 vs 0.545, however, mean(c(0.85, 0.9, 0.36, 0.32)) is not 0.545. 0.545 is mean(x2[-j,], na.rm = TRUE) from the source code. mean(c(0.85, 0.9, 0.36, 0.32)) would equal 0.6075, which would be mean(x2[j,], na.rm = TRUE). Can you check whether this is a bug?